# Different MANIFEST.MF for default jar-file and tests.jar

Tags: java, maven, package, manifest.mf, maven-jar-plugin

I'm trying to create different `MANIFEST.MF` files for the jar-packaged artifacts and the test-jar-packaged. The `maven-jar-plugin` being used to add additional stuff into the `MANIFEST.MF` - that works perfectly so far. But if I'd like to chose different template file for the `MANIFEST.MF` for the testproject, Maven only uses the second referenced template for both artifacts...

How can I get Maven to use the `PROD-MANIFEST.MF-template` for the normal jar-packaging and the `TEST-MANIFEST.MF-template` for test-jar-packaging?

```
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>test-manifest-mf</id>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>test-jar</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
            <archive>
                <manifest>
                    <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                </manifest>
                <manifestFile>foo/TEST-MANIFEST.MF</manifestFile>
            </archive>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>

    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>default-manifest-mf</id>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>jar</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
            <archive>
                <manifest>
                    <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                </manifest>
                <manifestFile>foo/PROD-MANIFEST.MF</manifestFile>
            </archive>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrap each plugin configuration you have provided in a profile.

```
<profiles>
  <profile>
    <id>PROD</id>
    <build>
      <plugins>
        // your PROD plugin configuration
      </plugins>
    </build>
  </profile>
  <profile>
    <id>TEST</id>
    <build>
      <plugins>
        // your TEST plugin configuration
      </plugins>
    </build>
  </profile>
</profiles>
```

Then you invoke Maven with a profile

```
mvn package -P PROD
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: It only works if you call `mvn` twice.

`mvn package -P PROD`

`mvn package -P TEST`

If you insert a `clean` at the second call the first manifest won't be correct.

Comment: When you invoke Maven it builds and writes to the build directory.  So, yes a build will overwrite an earlier build's files.  That is normal behavior.  In fact all your Maven runs should include a call to `clean`; such as `mvn clean package -P PROD`.

Comment: But if I include a `clean` and perform a `maven -PTEST clean install` the default jarfile will contain the wrong MANIFEST.MF (because it's not built with profile `PROD`). Therefore this suggestion does not provide a valid solution for the problem. Tanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>test-manifest-mf</id>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>test-jar</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <archive>
            <manifest>
                <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
            </manifest>
            <manifestFile>foo/TEST-MANIFEST.MF</manifestFile>
          </archive>
        </configuration>
      </execution>

      <execution>
        <id>default-manifest-mf</id>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>jar</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <archive>
            <manifest>
              <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
            </manifest>
            <manifestFile>foo/PROD-MANIFEST.MF</manifestFile>
          </archive>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
```

This configuration is performing 2 different executions of the same plugin, each of which has its own archive configuration.

If there is a parent pom somewhere in your hierarchy that has the archive configured outside of an execution, like this:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <archive>
       ... other archive config ...
    </archive>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

then that configuration will be merged with what you have by default.  If you don't want that to happen, add the `combine.self` attribute to the `<archive>` element like so:

```
<archive combine.self="override">
```

as described in the [plugins section of the POM reference](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Plugins).